# Docusign: Add current Day, Month or Year Separately in a document

Tags: docusignapi

I created all the functionality that i need through Docusign API, but i can't find how to add Day, Month or Year from when the document opened, separately in the document.

When someone opens a Document, i want to place the current day or month or year in a different places of the document. I know that i can use DateSigned, but DateSigned returns something like this mm/dd/year.

For example i want to do something like this : This document was signed on **[day]** th day of **[current_month]**, **[year]**.

The result should be: **This document was signed on 24th day of January, 2019**

For the Day i was truing to use the formula Day(d) but it returns something like this **24.00**

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

DocuSign offers a tab designed specifically for this purpose, why not use that?  When tagging your documents for signature there are two tab types related to dates:

- `Date` tab
- `Date Signed` tab

The `Date` tab is used to populate with a given date provided by the sender.  The `DateSigned` tab is a read-only tab that will always display the current date (ie the date when the recipient is signing the document).

---

To achieve what you are looking for you can either use the `DateSigned` tab which will automatically populate with the current date (though it won't be in the elongated format that you seek), or you can use a `DateSigned` tab AND separate formula tabs to grab the individual day, month and year values and display on your doc.

For example, I just tested the following and it worked:

1. Create a new template in your sandbox account.
2. Add a Date Signed tab somewhere to the document and give it a Label of `dateSigned1`.
3. Add a formula tab to the document also and give it the following formula:

   `Day([dateSigned1])`
4. Send the template.

This will in turn show today's current date (in the `dateSigned` tab) and it will also show the current day of the month through the formula field.  Once you get that working you can add the month and year then replicate the request through your API integration.

Comment: How can i use the Date tab to fill my blank spaces with the date that the Receiver open the document? I don't want the Receiver to fill the date. I want it to populated the exactly time that the Receiver opens the document.

Comment: I just updated my answer to add more info and provide more context, hope that helps.

Comment: I can get the Day of DateSigned, but there is no formula value for Month or Year.  Plus, we'd probably need the Month as a string (January, February, etc.) versus the month number.  I could prefill these values with the API, but the date I create the request and the date it was actually signed would probably not match (lawyers, you know).

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I see Day() but not Month() or Year()